# How can I use fopen function on PHP with a dynamic file path?

Tags: javascript, php, json, file, header

I need to read a file and then upload that content to a text area, but I let the client choose the file, but, I don't have any idea to do it.

I already have something, the code already read the file and upload it, but, its only with a specific route...

This is what I have:

```
$file_name = 'C:/Users/Downloads/'.$doc_name;
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$data =  array();
$file = fopen($file_name, "r+") or exit ("Error trying to open the file.txt");
while ($linea = fgets($file)){
    if(feof($file)) break; 
    $data[]=$linea;
}
fclose($file);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: what are you want to do? your code just open a file and echo the content?

Comment: When you say "but I let the client choose the file", you mean the user select a file in the browser from their computer and then you show the contents of that file in a textarea of the current page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your problem. 
You should always know where the uploaded files are going to. You should already have a directory, and add the file to that directory. Or if you want to create a directory based on some condition you can use [PHP function mkdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).

Assuming the file is uploaded/submitted through a POST request.

You should catch the file within the submit and do something like this.

```
<form action="uploadedFiles.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select file to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
    </form>
```

`$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` is the file submitted

```
$target_dir = 'C:/Users/Downloads/';
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

[basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) is another PHP function that gets you the file name

Hope it helps you, if not, try to specify the problem a bit more and show a bit more code also.

Edit: And also you should check the file size and extension to avoid security issues.

Edit of Edit: In case I didn't make myself clear. You should check file extension against a "WhiteList"/"BlackList" of file extensions and deny or allow the upload.

Comment: Checking the extension avoids no security issues.